# Xaml Intellisense : specify the binding context of a property type of a custom element

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, intellisense

I have a Xamarin forms project and I created a layout with an `ItemsSource` and an `ItemTemplate` property.

I bind a list to my itemsSource and then the layout create the items based on the itemTemplate.

Everything works fine except I would like to get the right intellisense suggestion when I create the `ItemTemplate`. I would like to spectify that the `BindingContext` of my `ItemTemplate` is of type `T` if my ItemsSource is `List<T>`.

I don't know how I can specify this in my code. Do you have an y suggestion or at least some google keywords?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: BindingContext  do you need in xaml or in .cs file?

Answer (score 0):

```
<ListView x:Name="ListViewName">
</ListView>
```

And then call it in Xaml.cs:

```
    public class ClassName
    {
    public ClassName()
    {
    var control = ListViewName;
    }

    }
```